# Strange performance drop after innocent changes to a trivial program

Tags: java, performance

Imagine you want to count how many non-ASCII chars a given `char[]` contains. Imagine, the performance really matters, so we can skip our favorite [slogan](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

The simplest way is obviously

```
int simpleCount() {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        result += string[i] >= 128 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you think that many inputs are pure ASCII and that it could be a good idea to deal with them separately. For simplicity assume you write just this

```
private int skip(int i) {
    for (; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string[i] >= 128) break;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Such a trivial method could be useful for more complicated processing and here it can't do no harm, right? So let's continue with

```
int smartCount() {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = skip(0); i < string.length; i++) {
        result += string[i] >= 128 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's the same as `simpleCount`. I'm calling it "smart" as the actual work to be done is more complicated, so skipping over ASCII quickly makes sense. If there's no or a very short ASCII prefix, it can costs a few cycles more, but that's all, right?

Maybe you want to rewrite it like this, it's the same, just possibly more reusable, right?

```
int smarterCount() {
    return finish(skip(0));
}

int finish(int i) {
    int result = 0;
    for (; i < string.length; i++) {
        result += string[i] >= 128 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then you ran a [benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/NonAsciiCounterBenchmark.java) on some *very long* random string and get this
[image: img]
The parameters determine the ASCII to non-ASCII ratio and the average length of a non-ASCII sequence, but as you can see they don't matter. Trying different seeds and whatever doesn't matter. The [benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/NonAsciiCounterBenchmark.java) uses [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper), so the usual gotchas don't apply. The results are fairly repeatable, the tiny black bars at the end denote the minimum and maximum times.

*Does anybody have an idea what's going on here? Can anybody reproduce it?*

Comment: FYI, Java microbenchmarks are difficult to get right: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp12214/

Comment: I don't understand how the smart algorithm is smarter than the simple one. It simply uses two loops instead of one, and each loop does basically the same thing: comparing every character with 256. So the algorithm is more complex, and thus less optimizable.

Comment: @JB Nizet: But these are separate methods, so they can be optimized independently. And they're also very trivial, even when everything gets inlined. Actually, the original problem is more complicated and special-casing ASCII would help.

Comment: You're doing it the right way: you measure, using good tools, the performance of every algorithm. So just pick the one that is the fastest. Trying to guess how the JIT optimizes the code is (at least to me, but I guess to almost everyone) an impossible task.

Comment: As an aside, ASCII ends at 127, not 255. In unicode, the 128-255 range is the Latin-1 Supplement block.

Comment: You don't have to guess how the JIT optimises the code - you can use the [-XX:+PrintAssembly](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) flag to find out exactly what is being executed. I suspect the real challenge will be understanding why some particular bit of compiled code is fast or slow.

Comment: Could it be that Java is smart enough to optimize array access not to include boundary checks in simpleCount?

Comment: Please separately benchmark `finish` and `skip` and show where the time is going. Is `skip` really as fast as you think it is?

Comment: @Alex D: The point is that `skip` bails out after a few chars (the probability that let's say all first 1000 chars are ASCII is negligible) and there is 1000000 chars in total. So whatever `skip` does and however long it takes, it can't matter.

Comment: How.long are the very long Strings? Do they still fit in CPU cache?

Comment: I can see only one difference. `timeSmart` subtracts `-1` in every loop. That would explain the performance difference to `timeSimple` but than, why is `timeSmarter` even slower?

Comment: @jboi: They're 1000000 chars, see the linked [benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/NonAsciiCounterBenchmark.java). You mean probably `skip` rather then `timeSmart` and the `-1` doesn't belong there, fixed (no different result).

Comment: @maaartinus, you may be right, but when you are analyzing the performance of a program, and especially when the results are not as you expect, it is *never* a good idea to assume. Check everything, assume nothing. Even if you are right this time, this frame of mind will serve you well in the future when troubleshooting things.

Comment: Try this article: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/RangeCheckElimination

Comment: Won't `for ( int result = 0, i = 0; i < string.length ; i++ ) { result += ... }` do `string.length` additions and assignments?  Since this _is_  a micro-optimization, it seems like it would make sense to avoid that extra work and just do `if ( ... ) result++;`.  Then you only do O(`result`) additions and assignments.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: The real program does it, this was a simplified example.... and actually the problem cause, see the accepted answer. The JVM is free to do such optimizations (it's not volatile) and usually does it, but not this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

The difference is in the possibility for the optimizer/CPU to predict the number of loops in `for`. If it is able to predict the number of repeats up front, it can skip the actual check of `i < string.length`. Therefore the optimizer needs to know up front how often the condition in the for-loop will succeed and therefore it must know the value of `string.length` and `i`.

I made a simple test, by replacing `string.length` with a local variable, that is set once in the `setup` method. Result: `smarterCount` has runtime of about `simpleCount`. Before the change `smarterCount` took about 50% longer then `simpleCount`. `smartCount` did not change.

It looks like the optimizer looses the information of how many loops it will have to do when a call to another method occurs. That's the reason why `finish()` immediately ran faster with the constant set, but not `smartCount()`, as `smartCount()` has no clue about what `i` will be after the `skip()` step. So I did a second test, where I copied the loop from `skip()` into `smartCount()`.

And voilà, all three methods return within the same time (800-900 ms).

[image: Different runtimes]

Comment: By "local variable, that is set once in the setup method" you mean a field, right? I extended [the benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/NonAsciiCounterBenchmark.java) and got [some results](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/218eb3e6-be40-4f38-9d93-4f78dca52360) showing that you're probably right. Agreed?

Comment: Field: Yes, that's what I mean. Do you also have the source code for `timeSmarter2` ?

Comment: Sure, see the [first link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/NonAsciiCounterBenchmark.java) in my comment above. I cached it (and the `string` too) in a local variable instead; this is something the JVM should do itself!

Comment: Ok, found it. Looks like the implementation of my changes, agreed. Really interesting, how loops (especially the condition) is optimizied.

Answer (score 3):

My tentative guess would be that this is about branch prediction.

This loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    result += string[i] >= 128 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Contains exactly one branch, the backward edge of the loop, and it is highly predictable. A modern processor will be able to accurately predict this, and so fill its whole pipeline with instructions. The sequence of loads is also highly predictable, so it will be able to pre-fetch everything the pipelined instructions need. High performance results.

This loop:

```
for (; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
    if (string[i] >= 128) break;
}
```

Has a dirty great data-dependent conditional branch sitting in the middle of it. That is much harder for the processor to predict accurately.

Now, that doesn't entirely make sense, because (a) the processor will surely quickly learn that the break branch will usually not be taken, (b) the loads are still predictable, and so just as pre-fetchable, and (c) after that loop exits, the code goes into a loop which is identical to the loop which goes fast. So i wouldn't expect this to make all that much difference.

Comment: That's good point... except for that the second loop gets terminated after a few chars and thus should play no role.

Comment: Hmm, yes. Have you experimentally verified the skip loop really does only run for a few characters?

Comment: Yes, I have. Did you consider that `string[i] >= 128 ? 1 : 0` can (but needn't) be translated using a branch?

Comment: Even if it was compiled as a branch, i would guess (this is all guesswork i'm afraid!) that it would be a branch that would not pose much of a problem for the processor: it would be a forward branch with a short distance to the rejoining of the two arms, so the processor should be able to speculate down both sides.

Comment: We don't need to speculate, I was curious and [investigated it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689214/strange-branching-performance). The JVM quite often fails to show its best.